# interrupt based recieve function in socket programming

Tags: c

I am new to socket programming. My program is based on rawsockets. I need to create a raw socket for communicating between two threads. My superior wants my receive function to be interrupt based or in other words the sockets should be non blocking. could anyone help me out as in what function i must use . I checked in net for several solution but nothing satisfying.

Comment: What platform are you expected to support? Linux? Windows? Can you show what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Read about select and accept.  Beej is a good resource.

Comment: tnx. Actually i am using linux based platform.